# How to stop a minor mode from auto-loading in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, package, minor-mode, install, autoload

The `smartparens` minor mode is quite annoying to me, so I want to have it disabled on default. However, I don't want to uninstall it, in case I need it someday.

Can I disable a minor mode without uninstalling it?

Comment: Why is it enabled in the first place?  Are you using an Emacs configuration that's not your own?

Comment: Put this in your init file after `smartparens` is loaded (and after whatever is turning it on turns it on): `(smartparens-mode -1)`. But it's better to not turn it on in the first place, so look for where that's happening.

Comment: @wasamasa I forgot to say that I'm using Spacemacs. Question tag edited. My bad.

Comment: You can add `smartparens` to `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages`, it should cascading disable smartparens everywhere it is referenced in spacemacs.

Comment: @syl20bnr But it seems that doing this would also uninstall the package...

Comment: @SunQingyao in the case of smartparens it won't be uninstalled because it is a dependency of other packages like evil-lisp-state package, but you will lose the Spacemacs configuration for smartparens. Let me find a solution for you.

Comment: I added and edited an answer which explains how I came with the solution, I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to know what Spacemacs configures about smartparens you can `SPC h SPC` and type `smartparens`, you'll get a list of all the places where smartparens is configured, choose the candidate `smartparens (owner: spacemacs-editing layer)` to go to the code configuring the package. In the code you can see that in the `:init` section of `use-package` we setup some hooks.

Spacemacs enables an hidden feature of use-package which allows to define hooks for `:init` and `:config` blocks.

So you can add a `:post-init` use-package hook in your `dotspacemacs/user-init` function whose job is to remove the hooks:

```
(spacemacs|use-package-add-hook smartparens
  :post-init
  (remove-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'smartparens-mode)
  (remove-hook 'comint-mode-hook 'smartparens-mode)
  (remove-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook
               'spacemacs//conditionally-enable-smartparens-mode))
```

Comment: It works like magic, thank you! However, to encourage potential answers, please let me wait for a while before I accept this answer.

Comment: Also, do you know how to eagerly load a package when Emacs starts up? Please see [my comment to the other answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/30633/14867#comment-47196) for the background.

Comment: You can explicitly require it in your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function.

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach besides the ones mentioned in the comments. All of these choices expand the configurability of Emacs. You may want to look into Shingo Fukuyama's package, [manage-minor-mode](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/manage-minor-mode), which is also on MELPA.

> Can I disable a minor mode without uninstalling it?

Yes. With `M-x manage-minor-mode`, you can toggle any [minor-mode](/questions/tagged/minor-mode) selectively and temporarily. How selective and how temporary is up for your exploration, but this is an option to consider. I use it for seeing the list of currently active minor modes. I'd think [spacemacs](/questions/tagged/spacemacs) would have had a feature like this.

Comment: How can I installed a package locally? MELPA does have a package called [manage-minor-mode](https://melpa.org/#/manage-minor-mode), but adding `manage-minor-mode` to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` gave me an `- Unknown layer manage-minor-mode declared in dotfile. ` warning.

Comment: OK, I've installed it now. However, `manage-minor-mode` is lazily loaded, making it incapable of doing anything until I **explicitly** load it with `M-x manage-minor-mode`. How to make it automatically loads when Emacs starts up?

Comment: Just `(require 'manage-minor-mode)` before using it ;-)